# What happens when casting double to float?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

Suppose that the closest float values to a double value `d` are `f1` and `f2`, so that `f1` < `d` < `f2`. Which will be the result of casting `d` to float in C99? `f1` or `f2`? Consider these two cases:

1. if `d - f1 > f2 - d`
2. if `d - f1 < f2 - d`

I have assumed that d itself cannot be represented by any float value exactly.

Comment: May be of assistance: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/FE_round

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C 2018 6.3.1.5 discusses conversions between real floating types and says:

> … If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.

Common C implementations use round-to-nearest by default, with ties rounded to the candidate with the even low bit.

The rounding mode is reported by `FLT_ROUNDS`, declared in `<float.h>` and specified in 5.2.4.2.2 9:

> The rounding mode for floating-point addition<sup>1</sup> is characterized by the implementation-defined value of FLT_ROUNDS:
>
> −1 indeterminable
>
> 0 toward zero
>
> 1 to nearest
>
> 2 toward positive infinity
>
> 3 toward negative infinity

The round mode may be changed by the `fesetround` function declared in `<fenv.h>`, although support for it and the `FENV_ACCESS` pragma it requires are spotty.

The C standard also provides Annex F that C implementations may adopt. In that case, the default rounding mode during compilation and execution is round-to-nearest ties-to-even per F.8.2 1:

> During translation the IEC 60559 default modes are in effect:
>
> — The rounding direction mode is rounding to nearest…

and F.8.3 1:

> At program startup the floating-point environment is initialized as prescribed by IEC 60559:
>
> …
>
> — The rounding direction mode is rounding to nearest.

My understanding is IEC 60559 is functionally equivalent to IEEE 754.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> I suspect “addition” is an error in the standard and is intended to be “arithmetic.”